# Is there any way to get serial number of my motherboard programmatically

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Is there any approach to get serial number of my motherboard programmtically may be just under the `Linux` with `cat` some system file?

Comment: you may want to check `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/` directory.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times before, e.g. http://askubuntu.com/a/179959/503184. Did you google your question? (If you don't want to start another program: Since the tools are open source they tell you how.)

Comment: Oh, again someone trying to tie a software license to the actual hardware?

Comment: Like arkascha hints at, making it a license violation to repair your computer will make your customers really angry.

Comment: @BoPersson agreed. But it's often not the programmers, that make decisions like this. :(

Answer (score 4):

Use the entries in `/sys/class/dmi/id/`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[256];
    FILE* f = fopen("/sys/class/dmi/id/board_serial", "r");
    fgets(&buf[0],sizeof(buf),f);
    printf("ID: %s\n",&buf);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

With qt you can simply do `QFile file("/sys/class/dmi/id/board_serial");` followed by `QByteArray line = file.readLine();` or use `QTextStream`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work under regular user... Requires root permissions.